# woocommerce Custom Permalink for /shop/%product_cat% to /%product_cat%

Tags: woocommerce, permalinks

how to make custom link in woocommerce Product Permalinks.
from..

```
/shop/%product_cat%
```

to

```
/%product_cat%
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/    try this plugin

Comment: http://www.jeriffcheng.com/removing-product-woocommerce-product-permalinks-slugs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make custom link on wordpress you should use permalinks. In permalinks option, you can do any link structure. First you go permalinks. Then change link on the product permalinks section. On the bottom, custom base write /%product_cat% and save. That's it.